# Alloc more than one object at the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsobject, nsset

I would like to know how to allow more than one object at the time. I am looking for something like NSSet with 50 empty Objects.

The reason for that is that I have a intensive work with a lot of allocations (1.000.000) and it is very time consuming to to it per one bases. (Alloc method is time expensive).

Comment: Why do you need so many instances on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, there are two runtime functions that allow you to create/destruct an object located in a pre-allocated block of memory:

```
/** 
 * Creates an instance of a class at the specific location provided.
 * 
 * @param cls The class that you wish to allocate an instance of.
 * @param bytes The location at which to allocate an instance of \e cls.
 *  Must point to at least \c class_getInstanceSize(cls) bytes of well-aligned,
 *  zero-filled memory.
 */
OBJC_EXPORT id objc_constructInstance(Class cls, void *bytes) 
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_3_0)
    OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;

/** 
 * Destroys an instance of a class without freeing memory and removes any
 * associated references this instance might have had.
 */
OBJC_EXPORT void *objc_destructInstance(id obj) 
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_3_0)
    OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Totally untested example usage (ARC must be disabled in the @implementation file):

```
+ (void)allocInPlace:(void *)buffer
{
    objc_constructInstance(self, buffer);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    objc_destructInstance(self);
}

size_t instanceSize = class_getInstanceSize(MyClass.class);

// This may not be enough, since we need to ensure that object instances are 16-byte aligned
void *buffer = calloc(instanceSize, numObjects);

for (size_t i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    // Need to ensure that this is 16-byte aligned
    void *objBuffer = buffer + (instanceSize * i); 
    [mySet addObject:[[MyClass allocInPlace:objBuffer] init]];
}
```

You'll need to hang onto `buffer` and `free()` it when no longer needed.

**However** you should probably just use a C array of structs if possible. The technique I've used here runs against standard Obj-C practice and is error-prone (if, for example, you free the buffer before all objects have been destructed then Bad Things will happen).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two things that I don't understand. 1. You still use for loop through all object (numObject), and 2.if I understand this code correctly You create one object of instance MyClass whit big size, but no more normal-size objects.

Comment: One block of memory holds many instances. If profiling suggests that a large number of small allocations is causing performance issues, it may fix them by performing one large allocation instead.

Comment: (The address passed to each init is different because of the pointer arithmetic)

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article on Cocoa With Love [Alternative Objective-C object allocation for large arrays](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/08/alternative-objective-c-object.html) about allocation

Comment: The method described there is no longer supported, as the layout of an object is effectively private since iOS 7 deprecated direct `isa` access.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux is Apple provide some alternative ways?

Comment: `objc_constructInstance(Class cls, void *bytes)` and `objc_destructInstance(id obj)` might work